# Bi-directional DC Motor Controller

Tags: motor, dc, control

[image]

I am using small 1 AMP DC motor the speed of which is controlled by a small controller that actually generates a variable V from 3 to 12V. I can change the direction of the motor by using a DPDT switch in the controller out. However, to prevent damage, I want to have some kind of circuity that will not start the motor in the reverse direction immediately. But first stop it with a decay and then start it with a delay.

How can I implement this in place of the DPDT switch?

Comment: The best way would be to control you speed controller and the DPDT relay at the same time. When you want to reverse the motor direction ramp the motor voltage to 0V, flip the relay, and ramp the voltage back to the previous setting. How do you control the speed controller voltage? Does it have a potentiometer?

Comment: Yes it has a potentiometer. Okay can the voltage be dropped to 0V automatically?

Comment: Automatically? You would have to control the pot. I'd add a microcontroller between the pot and the speed controller. The pot would be connected to the ADC on the micro and the micro would use a digital pot (e.g. MCP41xxx) to set the speed controller's voltage. The micro would control your DPDT relay as well, plus a button to set the rotation direction. Sounds like a really neat project to me.

Comment: With all honesty I have no clue as how to get done what you said but sounds very exciting.

Comment: I could sketch out a block diagram for you if you're interested in build it. The C code for the micro wouldn't be trivial but quite simple and a lot of fun too.

Comment: Yes I am definitely very much interested. I do know a bit of Pure C coding. Have to see if the Turbo C compiler would run on Windows 7. I can make out the circuit of the regulator if that helps.

Comment: To keep this simple can you just add another relay to cut the voltage before flipping your DPDT relay?

Comment: If you want to start with the micro use Arduino Nano (~$5). The C compiler is free and you program it through USB.

Comment: Yes I can add a relay. The one in the diagram is a DPDT switch though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27515/discussion-between-budwhite-and-alex).

Comment: Any relay would do. Even SPST. Connect it between the positive output of the regulator and your DPDT. Before changing the direction disconnect the SPST relay and wait until the motor stops turning. Then flip the direction relay and energize the SPST again.

Comment: So no need of the microprocessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drew a simple schematic of the idea we were talking about yesterday. I think it's not necessary to ramp the motor speed down and up before and after switching its direction. I'd be nice but is just unnecessarily complicates things. [image]

It uses a microcontroller to control 2 relays. The SPST relay is used to cut power to the motor while the direction is changed. The additional pushbutton is for changing the motor direction.
The code will be trivial. Essentially it will monitor the direction pushbutton in a loop. If it's pressed it will switch the SPST off, wait for motor to stop spinning, flip the DPDT relay, and energize the SPST relay again. The time to wait for the motor to stop spinning has to measured and correctly set in the code.

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, any specific microcontroller I should use?

Comment: I use Arudino Nano for all my hobby needs. Dirt cheap ($3.20 today at banggood), small, and easy to program in C. This one is more than enough for this design. You'll still have enough I/Os left to add a few LEDs to make it look cool.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is H-bridge Circuit.

To change the direction of motor, you need to reverse the polarity of supply to the motor.

[image]

Above image is an H-bridge made out of Transistors ( Darlington - TIP120 - NPN )

When Q1 and Q3 are turned on by providing 5V to Base, they conduct; hence motor turns in Clockwise direction [**see foot note**]. Q2 and Q4 are turned on, motor turns in Counter Clockwise direction [**see foot note**].

Integrated H-bridges are available i.e.  "L298N" , It can drive 2 Motors in both directions.

For smooth start and stop, you can use PWM.

*[Depends on how you connect the motor. Terminals of motor which connect to the junction.]*

*Image Courtesy - Google Images*

Comment: Thank you. So with this circuit, is it possible to decay the stop and delay the start? I will not be able to use a PWM controller and the motor manufacturer specification clearly states the motor can get damaged by PWM controllers on mid and high RPMs.

Comment: This circuit is a H-Bridge. For better understanding of the concept, i have included the picture. About speed control/smooth operation. You need to use PWM. As far i know Motors don't go haywire when speed is controlled using PWM.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace everything (including variable voltage PSU) with H-Bridge PWM controlled.

Comment: The controller has come with the motor. They do not suggest to use PWM DC controllers as the PWM controllers heat up these motors in mid and high speed ranges.

Comment: And what kind of driving technique do they use? PWM is just a normal thing to use with DC motors.

Comment: I think they are just using a simple variable voltage regulation.